# what can we call this?

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

I have recently received this woody puzzle toy. What's its name ? [image: photo 1]

[image: photo2]

Comment: It's called a wooden fidget toy/puzzle, though it's not so much a puzzle as a toy for, well, fidgeting.

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't a puzzle toy, just a toy. A puzzle toy would be something like a Rubik's cube where you are expected to create a certain outcome. With this, there is no expected outcome, so it's not really a puzzle, only a toy.

Comment: Co-incidentally, I just saw a peddler selling something very similar to this on my way to work today.  In his demo, he quickly shaped it into all the letters from A to Z, one after the other.  These toys typically come with a sheet with diagrams of interesting shapes like animals that you can make (similar to Origami).  So in a way, it is a puzzle in the sense that you can try to figure out how to make it into something specific.

Comment: If it has no official name, I kinda like your 'woody puzzle toy' name...

Comment: Seconding the woody love

Comment: I call it: nnuucccnnuuu

Answer (score 5):

The product you have is a Wood Fidget Puzzle manufactured by Toysmith. It is twelve ½" non-toxic stained wooden blocks.

Toysmith only sells this product [wholesale to retailers](https://www.toysmith.com/faqs/), so there's no official product page for me to link to.

> **CAN I ORDER ONLINE?**
>   Toysmith is a wholesale supplier to retail stores and promotional markets, we do not sell direct to the public.

---

That said, this particular toy is often marketed as a [stim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimming) toy for fulfilling children's sensory needs, rather than as a puzzle.

Here are some retailers who do sell it online:

- [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YRZ5QTE)
- [Sensory Kids® Store](http://www.sensorykidstore.com/wood-fidget-puzzle/dp/21665)
- [Project Sensory](http://www.projectsensory.com/product/wood-fidget-puzzle/)

Answer (score 2):

It's called a Kibble Cube and has [colored](http://www.twistypuzzles.com/cgi-bin/puzzle.cgi?pkey=958) or [patterned](http://www.twistypuzzles.com/cgi-bin/puzzle.cgi?pkey=672) variants.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't [the product](http://www.officeplayground.com/wooden-fidget-puzzle-p1466.html) that [OP has](http://www.sensorykidstore.com/wood-fidget-puzzle/dp/21665).

Comment: @Will, why don't you provide an answer, since neither of the existing answers are quite correct (both are close)?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the Flexi Puzzle made by Brainwright.
http://www.brainwright.com/products/display/8001D
However, I think the marketed version is made from plastic, while yours seems to be painted wood.
The Flexi puzzle booklet shows drawings of various shapes with all or just some of the blocks coloured. You then have to copy that, making sure you get the colours correct.